# I'm trying to post form data from select inputs in Laravel. (What I have works if I use text boxes)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post, drop-down-menu

resources\views\weapons\index.blade.php (Has about eight of these all with unique names)

```
    <select name="platform" class="form-control"  id="platform" placeholder = "Platform" >
                            <option value="All">Platform</option>
                            <option value="PC">PC</option>
                            <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                            <option value="Xbox">XBOX</option>
    </select>
<form method="post" action="{{ route('weapons.store') }}" id="myForm">
```

```
wep.php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\WeaponsController;
Route::resource('weapons', 'WeaponsController');
```

WeaponsController.php (I wish I knew how to add additional functions to this? Any time I try I get undefined function.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true));    
        //Weapon::create($request->all()); 
        $request->get('platform');
        echo $request;
```

The $_POST array contains this:
Array ( [_token] => k6c6YQYaXVwqzDlsgCxyy5FckKs7Kgkn1IatV0oV [Cancel] => Delete [notes] => ) Cancel, Delete and notes are input other than select, but none of my eight or so select choices are received?
This is the model: weapon.php

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class weapon extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'platform', 'username', 'player','level','prefix','weapon','primary','secondary','value','notes'
    ];
}

I'm very new to Laravel and MCV in general I've built what I have from repurposing this example: https://www.indeveloper.id/2020/01/tutorial-crud-laravel-6-menggunakan-orm.html?showComment=1592385889357 but I need to use select boxes not text boxes. I've been at this for days. A complete Method Route View & Controller working example would be AWESOME!!!
```

Comment: Why does your blade have the opening `form` tag after the select? Did the select field even become part of the form you intended it to be?

Comment: In Laravel use `dd(..vars)` instead of native `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<form` starts after `select`
put `<select> </select>` inside form then form values will be post

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('weapons.store') }}" id="myForm">
<select name="platform" class="form-control"  id="platform" placeholder = "Platform" >
                            <option value="All">Platform</option>
                            <option value="PC">PC</option>
                            <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                            <option value="Xbox">XBOX</option>
    </select>
    
    //other fields
    </form>
```

Comment: OMG, I feel so stupid. My example wasn't a 100% representation. Fortunately, I made the same error in my post as in my app.  The Form start was indeed inside the form and after most of my select boxes. I moved it as you suggested and now it works.